# Is there any guide, how to use DOM modifying javascript libraries, plugins with Blazor?

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I would like to use Blazor, preferably server side. I also would like to use, reuse my existing themes and visual design, however this many time includes using great javascript libraries, which modifies DOM programmatically to achieve their effect.

As far as I understand Blazor works with virtual DOM. What I do not understand how can the virtual DOM be in sync the real DOM, if any javascript code modifies the real DOM behind Blazors back.

The only way I could imagine, if there is a mechanism built in to Blazor to deal with this scenario, however even after years after Blazor in the scene, I can not see it documented, the issue I am talking about does not seem even a topic in Google searches.

**Question**

Is there any way to use Blazor with javascript libraries, which are modifying DOM? I mean have Blazor any built in mechanism to deal with this, or in case it have no, is there any common best practice?

Comment: Have you looked at [the Blazor homepage](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/apps/aspnet/web-apps/blazor) which has a section headed "JavaScript interop"?!

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/?WT.mc_id=dotnet-35129-website&view=aspnetcore-6.0#interaction-with-the-document-object-model-dom):

> Interaction with the Document Object Model (DOM)
>
> Only mutate the Document Object Model (DOM) with JavaScript (JS) when
> the object doesn't interact with Blazor. Blazor maintains
> representations of the DOM and interacts directly with DOM objects. If
> an element rendered by Blazor is modified externally using JS directly
> or via JS Interop, the DOM may no longer match Blazor's internal
> representation, which can result in undefined behavior. Undefined
> behavior may merely interfere with the presentation of elements or
> their functions but may also introduce security risks to the app or
> server.
>
> This guidance not only applies to your own JS interop code but also to
> any JS libraries that the app uses, including anything provided by a
> third-party framework, such as Bootstrap JS and jQuery.
>
> In a few documentation examples, JS interop is used to mutate an
> element purely for demonstration purposes as part of an example. In
> those cases, a warning appears in the text.
>
> For more information, see [Call JavaScript functions from .NET methods
> in ASP.NET Core Blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-6.0#capture-references-to-elements).

Comment: many thx....this is sad, because means not a line can be used from existing javascript libraries, not even Bootstrap javascript part. Also the doc mentioning ingerop is a very confusing noise here, because it is totally infifferent it is interop or "regular" javascript. The condition if rendered by Blazor is cloudy, because all element is rendered by Blazor or resides withn and element which rendered by Blazor...

Comment: To clarify what this section is saying, it means that you should not use JS interop to modify a part of the DOM that Blazor is also rendering or making changes to. However, if you have a completely blank element, and you pass it off to JS interop to completely control both the contents and attributes of the element, that is "safe" to do. A common scenario where this might be necessary is WebRTC. There are major gotchas to doing this, e.g. you have to handle cleanup outside of Blazor as Component lifecycle methods may occur after the DOM is already cleaned up.